# How to call method in order in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I am writing a socket application in Java. Here's the code:

```
client.Send("Server is closing the connection!");//Send() method will be executed in another thread.
client.Close();
```

I want `Close()` is always executed after `Send()` compete to make sure client receive the message before connection close. How to implement that?

I am a .NET programmer, so I'd like to use await like

```
await client.SendAsync("Server is closing the connection!");//Send() method will be executed in another thread.
client.Close();
```

in C#, how can I get the same result in Java?

---update---

About `Send()`:

```
private synchronized void Send(final String message)
{
    new Thread(() -> {
        //dosomething
    }.start();

}
```

Comment: how `Send` method look like?

Comment: Not related, please use `camel case` in your methods do not start in capital letter.

Comment: @YCF_L updated. `Send()` do things in a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join() method on the thread object to wait the send operation to finish and/or you can use the Observer pattern like this

```
public interface TransferListener{
    public void dataSent();
    public void connectionError();
}
```

You pass a instance that implements the TransferListener interface to the thread that calls the send method, and you notify the listener with the "dataSent" method if the operation was successful, or "connectionError" if something wrong occurred.

------ edit -----

To send in a different thread:

```
final Socket client = ...; // it must be final to be used in a inner class

Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      client.Send(...); //
   }
};

t.start();
```

To block the current thread until the thread "t" finishes:

```
t.join();
```

Also, if you don't want to block in order to do other computation before the send finish (or to not freeze the UI, for instance), you can use the observer pattern (that is the equivalent of delegates in C#) like I explained.